# How can I create a tenant with social provider with firebase admin SDK?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, multi-tenant, firebase-admin

I found in documentation that is only possible using the console. That is true? I think that should exists a way that I can do that via api, no?

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a tenant with social provider with firebase admin SDK?. I found in documentation that is only possible using the console

The [doc](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants#tenant_management) you refer to explains that:

> Using the Admin SDK, you can
> manage tenants programmatically from a secure server environment
> instead of using the console. This includes the ability to create,
> list, get, modify, or delete tenants

and you can find the following example for creating a tenant. Note that by "secure server environment" the doc means a server you own on which you execute Admin SDK code or a Cloud Function.

```
admin.auth().tenantManager().createTenant({
  displayName: 'myTenant1',
  emailSignInConfig: {
    enabled: true,
    passwordRequired: false, // Email link sign-in enabled.
  },
  // TODO: Remove if you don't want to enable multi-factor authentication.
  multiFactorConfig: {
    state: 'ENABLED',
    factorIds: ['phone']
  },
  // TODO: Remove if you don't want to register test phone numbers for use
  // with multi-factor authentication.
  testPhoneNumbers: {
    '+16505551234': '145678',
    '+16505550000': '123456'
  },
})
.then((createdTenant) => {
  console.log(createdTenant.toJSON());
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Handle error.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Renaud Tarnec. But that is not what I am trying to do. I can create the tenant, but how can I set o social provider via admin skd, like facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but it looks like adding social logins to a tenant via the admin sdk is not supported at the moment. See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants)

My best reporoduction of the table in markdown

| **Feature** | **Google Cloud Console** | **Admin SDK** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Email** | X | X |
| **OIDC** | X | X |
| **SAML** | X | X |
| **Social** | X |  |
| **Phone** |  |  |
| **MFA** | X | X |
| **Anonymous** | X |  |

Answer (score 0):

Your client side code is what facilitates the various social provider sign-in's. In other words, the admin SDK has nothing to do with it.

To setup the various social providers, see [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

Comment: Not true.  The provider has to be enabled on the app before the client side can use it.  Otherwise you would get an error: Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-allowed).

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to create a tenant programmatically using the SDK. Here's how I did it using the Ruby SDK.

```rb
# Create a new tenant in the Identity Provider and add the google.com IDP config
# References:
#  - https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants/create
#  - https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/create
#  - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/generated/google-apis-identitytoolkit_v2/lib/google/apis/identitytoolkit_v2/service.rb#L924
#  - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/generated/google-apis-identitytoolkit_v2/lib/google/apis/identitytoolkit_v2/service.rb#L1210
# @param tenant_name [String] The name of the tenant to create (eg: super-company)
# @return [String] The tenant ID
def create_tenant(tenant_name: "test-tenant")
  retry_on_error do
    begin
      # Create the tenant in the Identity Provider
      tenant_object = Google::Apis::IdentitytoolkitV2::GoogleCloudIdentitytoolkitAdminV2Tenant.new(
        name: tenant_name,
        display_name: tenant_name,
        allow_password_signup: true,
        enable_email_link_signin: false,
        disable_auth: false,
        enable_anonymous_user: false
      )

      tenant, error = @client_v2.create_project_tenant("projects/#{ENV.fetch('GCP_PROJECT_NAME')}", tenant_object)

      # Get the tenant ID from the name (eg: projects/PROJECT_ID/tenants/TENANT_ID)
      tenant_id = tenant.name.split("/").last if tenant

      raise error if error

      # Create a IDP config for the tenant (google.com)
      idp_config_object = Google::Apis::IdentitytoolkitV2::GoogleCloudIdentitytoolkitAdminV2DefaultSupportedIdpConfig.new(
        name: "google.com",
        client_id: ENV.fetch("GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID"),
        client_secret: ENV.fetch("GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET"),
        enabled: true
      )

      _, error = @client_v2.create_project_tenant_default_supported_idp_config("projects/#{ENV.fetch('GCP_PROJECT_NAME')}/tenants/#{tenant_id}", idp_config_object, idp_id: "google.com")

      raise error if error

      tenant_id
    rescue StandardError => e
      # Delete the tenant if it was created
      delete_tenant(tenant_id: tenant_id) if tenant_id

      raise(e)
    end
  end
end
```

You can find the full code here.

https://gist.github.com/tonystrawberry/41910f127e49dc80feedc5ec76aeb4cc